# Why https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html doesn't work when executing SharePoint project with gulp serve

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, gulp, localhost, content-security-policy

When I do gulp serve it should load the sharepoint side which it does and the localhost workbench but the last one gives a CSP error that I don't know how to solve.

This is the error:

> Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in other browsers? You can disable CSP in chrome easily:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden/related

However it's not a solution. The reason of this issue is your CSP does not allow for embedding iframe(your webpart) from another url(your localhost) into sharepoint site(some other adress I guess).

If your sharepoint is HTTPs this may not work without changing Content Security Policy.

When your solution is ready and everything is deployed there will be no problem, as hosts will be the same for sharepoint and webpart...

Comment: Now the problem with CSP is solved thank you but now it says:
workbench.html:1 GET https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html 404 (Not Found)